# Sumar todos los Array en una sola variable para mostrar en pantalla

Tags: array, linux, bash, shell-script

En el código, el $total2 de cada producto se va metiendo en un array de forma que cuando se responde "no" a la pregunta, tenemos "n" arrays. 
¿Qué bucle puedo hacer para sumarlos todos en una sola variable e imprimirlo por pantalla?

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
read -p "¿Desea seguir comprando?: " respuesta
while [ "$respuesta" == 'si' ]
   do
        read -p "¿Que producto va a comprar? " producto
        read -p "¿Cual es el precio de este producto?: " precio
        read -p "¿Que cantidad se llevará de este producto?: " cantidad
        let total2=expr $precio\*$cantidad
        echo "$producto ($precio €) X $cantidad = $total2 €"
        array[i]=$total2
       ((i++))
        read -p "¿Desea seguir comprando?: " respuesta
        if [ "$respuesta" == 'no' ]
         then
           break
         fi
   done
```

## aquí quiero sumar todos los arrays creados para mostrar esa suma en pantalla.

echo "El precio total de la compra es $suma €."

#

Comment: ¿Pero por qué no sumas los `$total2` para tener el precio absoluto? No veo la necesidad de arrays

Comment: Al usar el programa, se van introduciendo productos con un total cada uno. Con el array consigo que todos esos totales se guarden en algún sitio, si no en cada vuelta del while la varible $total2 se sustituirá de forma que al salir del bucle el valor de $total2 será el del último producto y los demás será como si nunca hubieran existido.

Comment: sí bueno entonces guardarlo en otra variable tipo `$total_acumulado` o similar, donde vas sumando los valores de `$total2` en cada iteración.

Comment: Solo he conseguido guardar los dos últimos productos en una variable, por eso pensé que sería mejor acumularlos en un array. Quizás con respecto a lo que me comentas hay algo sencillo que se me escapa, pero de esa forma no he conseguido solucionarlo.

Comment: mi punto es que si solamente quieres ir guardando el valor acumulado en euros, sin más, no hace falta más que guardar eso. El array sería para guardar más datos si quisieras imprimirlos finalmente desglosados

Comment: ¿Cómo hago para que ese valor acumule todo? No se me ocurre como hacer eso sin que se me sustituya todo y solo acumular los dos últimos totales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ve acumulando el valor total en una variable:

```
total2=$(( precio * cantidad ))
echo "$producto ($precio €) X $cantidad = $total2 €"
total=$(( total + total2 ))
```

Así, todo tu código puede quedar en algo así como:

```
read -p "¿Desea seguir comprando?: " respuesta
while [ "$respuesta" == 'si' ]
   do
        read -p "¿Que producto va a comprar? " producto
        read -p "¿Cual es el precio de este producto?: " precio
        read -p "¿Que cantidad se llevará de este producto?: " cantidad
        total2=$(( precio * cantidad ))
        echo "$producto ($precio €) X $cantidad = $total2 €"
        total=$(( total + total2 ))
        read -p "¿Desea seguir comprando?: " respuesta
        if [ "$respuesta" == 'no' ]
         then
           break
         fi
   done     

echo "Precio total a pagar: $total"
```